# iOS- Push notification issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently one of my php developer provided me push notification API for iOS devices

**The problem is :** If i run that api with respective parameter in any Browser(Chrome/Safari/Firefox and etc..) i am getting notification on foreground of iOS device. But not in iOS app(Xcode) itself

**In my app i used code like:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 // Register for Push Notitications, if running on iOS 8
   if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
 }
}
#pragma mark
#pragma mark -- Push Notification Delegate Methods
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:   (UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings{
//register to receive notifications
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{
// Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
devToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", devToken);
// My token is: cd2887c4093569b3eed142320f21a81e521e486cf5c40467390901d3a191398b
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:deviceToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error{
 NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
NSLog(@"%s..userInfo=%@",__FUNCTION__,userInfo);
}
```

**I am getting response:(in didReceiveRemoteNotification)**

```
{
aps =     {
    alert = "You're login successfully";
    sound = default;
};
```

}

This message is not showing on Status bar(top of the screen). Is there any issue in iOS side (or) PHP side

If the issue is in iOS side--> How can i do this

Here is my Testing Push notification  API:

https://shopgt.com/mobile1/iphone/register.php?device_type=2&email=sukhpal@anaad.net&regId=4d1d9067cc1382ecb8b0532831cce7fc8eb6fc388a6139060cd84712407a0ae5

Can you please help me out regarding this issue

Comment: iOS app(Xcode)    ---- do you mean if run on  simulator there is no notification

Comment: No, I am trying to run in Devices(iPhone 6plus & iphone 5s and etc..) only --> I know in simulator we can't show Remote notification. We can show only Local notification

Comment: you would need to give additional parameter `content-available:true` parallel to aps key go get notification on status bar

Comment: have u got deviceToken?

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize the view for showing Banner of Push Notification while the app in Foreground. You can use `JCNotificationBannerPresenter`. Follow the sample code using below link.

https://github.com/jcoleman/JCNotificationBannerPresenter

```
#import "JCNotificationCenter.h"
#import "JCNotificationBannerPresenterSmokeStyle.h"

- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification {
  NSString* title = @"Push Notification";
  NSDictionary* aps = [notification objectForKey:@"aps"];
  NSString* alert = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"];
  [JCNotificationCenter
   enqueueNotificationWithTitle:title
   message:alert
   tapHandler:^{
     NSLog(@"Received tap on notification banner!");
   }];
}
```

Hope it Helps you..!

Comment: ThanQ @Vidhyanand.,  I have one small doubt is it possible to set AppIcon with respect of message

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue, this is default behaviour.

The banner that appears at the top of the screen when you are on the Home screen does not appear when you are inside the app.

You need to get the app to do something with the notification yourself, inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. This could be showing an alert, adding a badge to the tab bar, etc. but banners only show when you are outside of the app.

Comment: OK. As per you're concern. If i opened the app(inside the app) and i run the above Testing push notification api in Browser. I am getting notification on Top of the screen. How it's possible at that time?

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing banners while the app is in the foreground. If you are then you have something else that is causing it, such as the same app installed twice under two different bundle IDs. This isn't usual behaviour and you need to expect that it won't be happening for most of your users.

Comment: If you don't mine can you please suggested me-->How would i show that response in Banner format

Comment: You could make a custom view that replicates the iOS banner and show that instead. It could be an opportunity to design the banner to fit aesthetically within the rest of your app rather than making an exact copy of the regular banners.

Comment: There are open source projects that you can use for this: eg https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aznotification